# Relationship between 3 tables in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database, relationship

I don't know what title I use for my question. I have a very common scenario in my classes. `ClassA` has a `one-to-one` relation with `ClassB` and `ClassC` also has a `one-to-one` relation with `ClassB`. The relationship is parent-child relationship. `ClassB` instance can't exist without `ClassA` and `ClassC`. I haven't much worked in database design. I don't know how I map this relation in tables.

What I have done is I create a table **'A'** for `ClassA`, table **'C'** for `ClassC` and two table for `ClassB` **'AB'** and **'CB'**. 'AB' table will be used for the relationship between `ClassA` and `ClassB` whereas **'CB'** table will be use for the relationship between `ClassC` and `ClassB`.

I want to know did I work correctly or not? and what if the relationship is one-to-many? If you think that scenario doesn't exist then tell me how this this could be possible, A `Location` has one `Address` and a `Contact` also has one `Address`.

**Code**

```
public  class Location{ // ClassA
String name ;
String description ;
Address add;

//getter setter

}
public class Address{  // ClassB 
String address1;
String address2;
String city;

//getter setter

}
public class Contact {  // ClassC
String firstName;
String lName;
Address add;

//getter setter
}
```

Comment: Add some data and show to make it look clearer. Too much theory!

Comment: In your code can you put alias A, B, C. As what you have explained in question doesn't match up in code.

Comment: ok let me update question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I see here, these are not one-to-one relationships. I've only worked with one-to-one relationships a few times in the last 10 years. The only reason you would like a one-to-one relationship is to cut down table sizes. For example if some columns will be null for most rows and those null columns are related logically, I will consider moving them into a different table. But that is indeed one-to-oneOrZero relationship.

Your case is one-to-many relationships. You can enforce that no two Locations share the same address but you will do it in the application layer, not the database layer.

In this case, you can have a foreign key on the 'many' side. i.e a address_id in the Location table and Contact table.

Comment: An address must belong to either location or Contact. then how I handle this scenario if I  put address_id as a foreign key in location and contact table?